# OctoberCMS - Creating file attachment in seeder

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I need to create a seeder that will import data from a csv file. The csv file contains the path to an image file that needs to be attached to the model.

In the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments) we find:

> You may also pass a string to the data attribute that contains an
>   absolute path to a local file.

```
$model->avatar = '/path/to/somefile.jpg';
```

Unfortunately I might be missing something. This is the relevant code:

**Model**

```
public $attachOne = [
    'image' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

**Seeder**

```
$product->image = '/path/image.png';
$product->save();
```

**Error**

The error is that the file is not being created. On top of that, no errors are shown in the migration log.

**PS:** When saving from an file upload field, everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you update the question with the error you're receiving when you run the seeder?

Comment: @Joseph sure! The problem is being silently ignored. I have updated the question.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem when I try it. However, following the example for multiple files works even if the relationship is attachOne: `$product->image()->create(['data' => '/path/image.png', 'is_public' => true]);` Perhaps it's a bug or the documentation is missing something?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing if my suggestion had any effect?

Comment: This apparently was a bug that was fixed in [build #402](http://octobercms.com/changelog):
https://github.com/octobercms/docs/pull/227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$file = new File;
$file->data = '/path/to/somefile.jpg';

$product->image = $file;
$product->save();
```

Comment: It worked! ````$product->image()->create(['data' => 'somefile.jpg']);```` worked as well.